# Isolines (level lines)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

The required data calculation (I need concentration) is already there. There is a grid (NxN) with a given step. By pressing the button according to the given formula, the concentrations were obtained at each point of this grid.

[image]

It is necessary to combine the obtained identical values of concentrations for the formations of the isoline.

[image]

This article: https://habr.com/ru/post/141881/ describes the code for plotting isolines, but I do not understand how to insert the obtained concentrations into this code and get isolines of values of the same concentrations.

Maybe someone have other ideas.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Lrp.png]

Comment: Which control are you using for the numbers? Will it be interactive? If you have the plot data it is simple to draw onto most controls in their Paint event. for this you will want to scale the e.Graphics object to fit the grid numbers to pixels ratio.. - An alternative idea would be to use an MSChart for the lines and maybe an image of the numbers as its background image.

Comment: @TaW I used chart element. I have concentration values at each grid point (1 picture), that is x, y, c (concentration).

Comment: Do you mean what we see is already a MSChart control?? Which charttype?

Comment: @TaW The first type of chart is what I have already done, the second is what I want to create.

Comment: Yes but is it a MSChart control? And which ChartType? Or are those just images?

Comment: @TaW Yes it is chart. I can drop a link to download the code, you can watch the whole program.

Comment: Um, no I'd rather not. Why don't you answer my questions?

Comment: @TaW Line and Spline

Comment: So what is the issue? Getting the data? Or combining the numbers with the Chartcontrol? - And how are those numbers displayed?

Comment: @TaW 
the code that I use to display the values I found on the forum. this code uses the chart element. I don't quite understand this code.
My task: I enter values into the textbox, using the formula c = a + b + x + y (this is an example of a formula), I calculate the concentration. the problem is to find the concentration values (c) at the grid nodes (100x100) with a step of 5. and it is necessary to find the same values and connect them on this grid. maybe I can use Paint or something else, but I don't know how.

Comment: @TaW I get your point, but how to use e.Graphics to scale the object in accordance with the ratio of grid numbers to pixels? Can you have some examples?

Comment: @TaW and how can I use MSChart for line displays? I need isolines (that is, each line will connect the same concentration value).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help. I don't understand what you actually have and what you need. Do you have the numbers? If yes, where are they? In a table, a datagridview? Or do you have to calculate them?

Comment: @TaW I have the numbers in a table, a datagridview. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: OK, so you can read the enumber from a DGV (or the Table). (I have asked for this information 3 hours ago..) - Eventually you want to draw those lines/curves onto the DGV? You need to a) find the coordinates and b) use `e.Graphics.DrawLines()` or DrawCurve from an array of Points or PointsF. and c) scale the graphics object to match the numbers. I won't go into calculating the numbers as I don't understand about your 'concentration' etc.. Let's assume you have an array of points. you need to x- andy-minimum and -maximums. Then you can calculate a scaling factor for x- and y-coordinates and..

Comment: ..do a `e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(fx, fy)`.

Comment: @TaW Can I use MSChart somehow? sorry for my questions. I am trying to show isolines that connect points in space with the same concentration of pollutants. (concentration is an environmental indicator in this work)

Comment: Yes, I think you could do that, too. You would make all backcolors transparent and overlay it on or nest it in the DGV. But really, the 1st step is to get the drawing coordinates.

Comment: @TaW thank you. I'll try it...

Comment: @TaW I have x and y values in datagridview. in the for loop, I indicate that x and y have values from 0 to 10. Then, using the formula c = x * y, I find the coordinate values. Each calculated s corresponds to x and y. I have a 10x10 grid. that is, (x1 = 1 y1 = 1 c11 = 1), (x1 = 1 y2 = 2 c12 = 2) and so on.
I still do not understand how to display this grid and where. Could you tell me on which element I can display the coordinates? In paintbox?

Comment: I thought you have the numbers in a DataGridView? You can add column- and rowheaders for the coordinates. And you can draw in the dgv.Paint event..